# How to read HLDA pin DMA Controller 8237 with Assembly Codes

Tags: assembly, dma, io

I trying to read HLDA Pin in 8237. But i can not find a literature(s) about it in Internet. In Assembliy codes.

The circuits is use for i/o cards in PCI or ISA BUS. addeds DMA Process with all. I use in to make a Digital Storage Oscilloscopes. And further for Fast Dourier Transform in Fast and real time Spectrum Analyzer card. May be above 5 MHz Bandwidth or more. Like the FNIRSI use in their Products.

I not create USB Device regarding to it serial data transfer which is very2 slow ngab. I am a white hacker in electronics engineering and Informatics. And i would like to shares it with you all here.

[image]

This pin will start all DMA Process after Requestin HRQ pin to Microprocessor X86.

How to enable pin HRQ and DACK use Assembly Codes.

The other questions will be :
How to read HLDA and DREQ pin DMA Controller 8237 with Assembly Codes.

[image]

What this Register Inisialites ALL ABOUT wihout Explanate HOW TO STARTING all process in this Case ABOUT STARTING ALL DMA Process with Assembly Codes ( HLDA Read from X86 )?

Comment: adhitronic - As I explained on a previous (now deleted) question of yours, PC programming is [off-topic](/help/on-topic) here. Also, you seem to be asking multiple questions (needs focus) and the specific questions are unclear (needs details or clarity) which are also reasons for closure here too. Therefore, sorry, your question is unsuitable for this site.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. It's not readable. It's a handshake pin, output from the CPU to 8237 input. It is used as the signal for the 8237 to determine when the bus is free for the 8237 to take over.

Even if it were possible to read it, it would be useless, as at the moment of IO bus cycle reading it, it would indicate bus is not free because there is an ongoing IO read cycle.

Comment: Yes sure i know it. But its the leackagesi basic to process all the DMA Process. Sure after Initializing all Registers and all programs needed in Assembly Codes.

Comment: I don't understand. You ask how to read  HLDA. I say it is impossible. You say you know it already. Why do you ask then?

Comment: I dont get is. How to start all process with out reading the Pin HLDA first. Im nearly to headache looking for how in the Internet.

Comment: Owh. I get an idea. Why not use HLDA to enable PIN 8237 CHIP ENABLED ? But its too complicated in those Design ?

Comment: @adhitronic Justme says that the CPU reads and writes HLDA **automatically**

Comment: Yeah. Its the CPU Sides @user253751. The queation about Chip 8237 DMA Controller sides. I need the codes ngab. basic process in it.

Comment: @adhitronic The 8237 does not use assembly code because it is not a CPU.

Comment: @adhitronic Your English is a bit hard to understand. I see that your normal language is probably Sundanese (but I could be wrong). Please try to use a translator instead, if possible, e.g. https://translate.google.com/?sl=su&tl=en&op=translate .

Comment: Yes i a quite person i. But i getting wild if in electronika projects. @user253751.